# Phone field not getting included in the contact form email in jquery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, email, contact-form

I am using WP Onetone theme and trying to add phone field in the contact form. I added field in HTML and also made following changes in js file which send ajax request for email. Phone number variable below is captured correctly by `JS` file and all validations are happening correctly for the phone field.

Email is sent but still phone number is not getting included. I am sure there must be code to receive this request and send email which is not including this field. Where should I make the additional changes?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    url:onetone_params.ajaxurl,
    data:"Name="+Name+"&Email="+Email+"&Phone="+Phone+"&Message="+Message+"&sendto="+sendto+"&action=onetone_contact",
```

Comment: Need more infomration.. Post your html too and show how you are getting values in `Phone` variable?

Comment: add the php that sens the email... the error should be there if you get your phone in js.